# Uploading File to Azure Blob Storage results in size 0

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Able to successfully create a container and upload any file in a created container. Having an issue after downloading a file (any uploaded file) they are always zero. Here is my code using C# in a NET.Core application.

```
            // Get a reference to a blob
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString: connectionString, blobContainerName: "test-container");
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        try
        {
            // Get a reference to a blob
            BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(uploadFiles.First().FileName);

            string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(uploadFiles.First().FileName);

            // Upload file data
            await blob.UploadAsync(filePath, true);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _ = e;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXQqw.png)

Image is attached to show what is inside the Auzure portal storage account, the size there is ZERO ?!

I am following documentation from Microsoft and they are also not setting any size explicitly when uploading a file.

Comment: Is an exception raised?

Comment: No exceptions I checked. Files are uploaded with NO exceptions except when they show up in Blob storage I see using the interface as 0 size. When I try to download using Azure interface they do download but when I open my pc can not open since they are zero size.

Comment: Whether the uploaded local file is intact, it seems that there is no problem on my side.

Comment: You were able to upload the file just fine? With the code provided? What modifications did you make?

Comment: Use the code you provided completely. There are currently two guesses, one is that the local file you uploaded is damaged, and the other is that the asynchronous method has not finished execution.

Comment: Please try to use the following code: `using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
await blob.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();`

Comment: @FrankGong your code worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can work:

```
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath); 
await blob.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true); 
uploadFileStream.Close();
```